# Google Charts - How to set two columns inside a general column in a table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to make a table using Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

This table is customized and has two general columns each with two more columns inside, like this one in the picture:

[image: Example of table with 2 columns inside a bigger column]

Is it possible to do it using GoogleCharts?